# How to format environment variables with spaces on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, spotify, spaces

So I'm following [this](https://github.com/benchmarkstudios/slackbox#installation) guide involving Spotify playlist integration on Slack. The guide says to create an environment variable called SPOTIFY_USERNAME. I'm very confused on how to format the value for this variable. My username shows up as "Ralph David Abernathy" as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

So should the value be `"SPOTIFY_USERNAME":"Ralph David Abernathy"` or `"SPOTIFY_USERNAME":"Ralph_David_Abernathy"`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. You can simply get the username by clicking `Copy Spotify URI` on this page:
[image]

The URI will look something like this `spotify:user:12345678`. So inputting `12345678` as the environment variable will work just fine.